# Android ToolBar can change back button color but not title color

Tags: android, toolbar, android-xml, android-appcompat

I want to change my `Toolbar` title color to blue. It stays white. I was able to set the back button but not the title color - am I missing something?

I've tried to change it at 3 different places:

**Activity**

```
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.detail_toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitleTextColor(0xff00ff99);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

**activity.xml**

```
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/detail_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:theme="@style/ToolBarStyle"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:titleTextColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
            app:subtitleTextColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"

            app:popupTheme="@style/ToolBarStyle" />
```

**v21 styles.xml**

```
    <!-- ToolBar -->
    <style name="ToolBarStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat">

    <item name="titleTextColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>
```

**styles.xml**

```
    <style name="ToolBarStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="titleTextColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>
```

**What am I missing?**
It stays white no matter what. I've even went through the 150 references to #ffffff in the whole project and nowhere is the toolbar referenced there.

targetSdk 26, running on Android 7.1.1

Answer (score 2):

Create custom `Toolbar` like this:

**toolbar_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@android:color/backgroundColor"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/blue"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Include it in you layout:

```
<include layout="@layout/toolbar_layout"/>
```

Use it in your activity's onCreate method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_card);

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    TextView toolbarTitle = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null)
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    toolbarTitle.setText("Your title");
    ...
}
```

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change this:

> android:titleTextColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"

to:

> app:titleTextColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"

in your **activity.xml** `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` section.

Comment: It should, Also no need this in styles.xml. Try to remove this line: <item name="android:titleTextColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item> Some style definition interfere to other. Should remove unnecessary items in styles

Comment: Hey mate, I've found the issue now. Will write answer in a minute

Comment: I've added my answer. Thanks a lot for your support tho, keep it up my friend!

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I have found the answer by literally stack tracing my code.

I have a PagerAdapter returning different fragments. I thought that each `Activity` was responsible to the `Tabbar` (it's a Master/Detail pattern for different tabs each) as I've had to set stuff like `setSupportActionBar()` which I've done in the subsequent `Activities`.

Stacktracing my code I've realized that there is a `CollapsingToolbarLayout` being find by view ID. This is where I set the bar's title. From there, I didn't find any title property but I've let auto complete lead me to `setCollapsedTitleTextColor` and `setExpandedTitleColor`.

So although the `getColor()` part is deprecated it's

```
bar.setCollapsedTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
bar.setExpandedTitleColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
```

Still no idea why all the other places I've set it at didn't do the trick but very happy it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

> In Layout file use the Toolbar as Child layout of AppBarLayout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

> Style.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

> Inside MainActivity

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       Toolbar  toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
```